# docker build IMAGE results in error but docker-compose up -d works fine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to the Docker. I am trying to create a docker image for the NodeJS project which I will upload/host on Docker repository. When I execute `docker-compose up -d` everything works fine and I can access the nodeJS server that is hosted inside docker containers. After that, I stopped all containers and tried to create a docker image from Dockerfiles using following commands:

```
docker build -t adonis-app .
docker run adonis-app
```

The first command executes without any error but the second command throws this error:

```
> adonis-fullstack-app@4.1.0 start /app
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! adonis-fullstack-app@4.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the adonis-fullstack-app@4.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-02-09T17_33_22_489Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me with this error and tell me what is wrong with it?

**Dockerfile I am using:**

```
FROM node

ENV HOME=/app
RUN mkdir /app

ADD package.json $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli && npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  adonis-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
    networks:
      - api-network
  adonis-api:
    container_name: "${APP_NAME}-api"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - adonis-mysql
    networks:
      - api-network

networks: 
  api-network:
```

Comment: Your node app is failing. Nothing to do with docker

Comment: By the way, `docker-compose build` can be used instead

Comment: You actually mount your app folder using volumes in the docker-compose. However you are not doing the same in your docker run command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is missing a `COPY` step to actually copy your application code into the image.  When you `docker run` the image, there's no actual source code to run, and you get the error you're seeing.

Your Dockerfile should look more like:

```sh
FROM node
WORKDIR /app     # creates the directory; no need to set $HOME
COPY package.json package.lock .
RUN npm install  # all of your dependencies are in package.json
COPY . .         # actually copy the application in
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Now that your Docker image is self-contained, you don't need the `volumes:` that try to inject host content into it.  You can also safely rely on several of Docker Compose's defaults (the `default` network and the generated `container_name:` are both fine to use).  A simpler `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```yaml
version: '3.3'    
services:
  adonis-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    # As you have it, except delete the networks: block
  adonis-api:
    build: .   # this directory is context:, use default dockerfile:
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - adonis-mysql
```

There's several key problems in the set of artifacts and commands you show:

**`docker run` and `docker-compose ...` are separate commands.**  In the `docker run` command you show, it runs the image, as-is, with its default command, with no volumes mounted, and with no ports published.  `docker run` doesn't know about the `docker-compose.yml` file, so whatever options you have specified there won't have an effect.  You might mean `docker-compose up`, which will also start the database.  (In your application remember to try several times for it to come up, it often can take 30-60 seconds.)

**If you're planning to push the image, you need to include the source code.**  You're essentially creating two separate artifacts in this setup: a Docker image with Node and some libraries, and also a Javascript application on your host.  If you `docker push` the image, it won't include the application (because you're not `COPY`ing it in), so you'll also have to separately distribute the source code.  At that point there's not much benefit to using Docker; an end user may as well install Node, clone your repository, and run `npm install` themselves.

**You're preventing Docker from seeing library updates.**  Putting `node_modules` in an anonymous volume seems to be a popular setup, and Docker will copy content from the image into that directory the first time you run the application.  The second time you run the application, Docker sees the directory already exists, assumes it to contain valuable user data, and refuses to update it.  This leads to  SO questions along the lines of "I updated my `package.json` file but my container isn't updating".

Answer (score 1):

Your docker-compose.yaml file has two services:

1. adonis-mysql
2. adonis-api

Only the second item is using the current docker file. As can be seen by the following section:

```
build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

The command `docker build .` will only build the image in current docker file aka adonis-api. And then it is run.

So most probably it could be the missing mysql service that is giving you the error. You can verify by running

```
docker ps -aq
```

to check if the sql container is also running. Hope it helps.

Conclusion: Use docker-compose.